# Is there any way to turn off the boot beep when starting a PS3?

Tags: ps3

When you turn on a Playstation 3 it makes a short high pitched noise. I've already tried looking around to see if there was anyway I could switch this sound off.

Is is possible to disable this sound?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the beep when you power on the PS3

You can't turn that off

Sony have had these "beeps" in many of their systems, they are generally annoying but there is no way to stop it, unless you opened the PS3 up and removed the speaker(hardware) that the noise is produced from